# I have a problem with this code where the buzzer won't work

Tags: arduino-uno, arduino-ide

```
const int buzzerPin = 7;
const int flamePin = 10;
int Flame = HIGH;
int redled = 8;
void setup() 
{
  pinMode(buzzerPin, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(redled, OUTPUT);

  pinMode(flamePin, INPUT);
  Serial.begin(12000);
}

void loop() 
{
  Flame = digitalRead(flamePin);
  if (Flame== HIGH)
  {
    digitalWrite(redled, HIGH);
  int i=0;
  do {
    digitalWrite(buzzerPin, HIGH);
    tone(buzzerPin,450);
    delay(200);
    noTone(buzzerPin);
    delay(200);
    
  }while (i<2);
  } 
  else
  {
    digitalWrite(buzzerPin, LOW);
    digitalWrite(redled, LOW);
  }
}
```

Comment: test the buzzer with the simplest code possible

Comment: We don't know anything about your buzzer or circuit, so there's little to offer in the way of help. Please make sure when posting code that it's formatted as code so people can actually read it. It's also helpful to include what *does* work, e.g., there are other factors in your code that could make it *seem* like the buzzer isn't working.

Comment: 450 is too low frequency for a piezo. use 3000

Answer (score 1):

**Here are the modifications I have done**

- I changed the Piezo Buzzer frequency to 3000 Hz
  The green Button simulates the Flame signal
- Change the RED LED from pin 8 to Pin 13 so that I don't have to use an external LED

**Here is the simulation output**

[image]

Observe the onboard LED going HIGH and the buzzer going off. You can find the project link [**here**](https://wokwi.com/arduino/projects/300993767428588045) where you can test with different Piezo buzzer frequency.

**Code**

```
const int buzzerPin = 7;
const int flamePin = 10;
int Flame = HIGH;
int redled = 13;
void setup() 
{
  pinMode(buzzerPin, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(redled, OUTPUT);  

  pinMode(flamePin, INPUT);
  Serial.begin(12000);
}

void loop() 
{
  Flame = digitalRead(flamePin);
  if (Flame== HIGH)
  {
    digitalWrite(redled, HIGH);
  int i=0;
  do {
    digitalWrite(buzzerPin, HIGH);
    tone(buzzerPin,3000);
    delay(200);
    noTone(buzzerPin);
    delay(200);
    
  }while (i<2);
  } 
  else
  {
    digitalWrite(buzzerPin, LOW);
    digitalWrite(redled, LOW);
  }
}
```

*Disclaimer: I am not the Wokwi creator but I support it since it is open source and free to use*

Comment: @Juraj fixed it

Comment: @Juraj I Doubt it. if the flame signal is high, he is triggering the alarm